# MATLAB compiler not working - build fail

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make my `final.m` file standalone, but MATLAB will not proceed with the ccompilation and it gets stuck every time:

```
    ant:
    <ant>
      <mkdir dir="C:\Users\TG\Desktop\updated\final\for_redistribution" />
      <mkdir dir="C:\Users\TG\Desktop\updated\final\for_testing" />
    </ant>
    mcc -C -o final -W WinMain:final -T link:exe -d C:\Users\TG\Desktop\updated\final\for_testing -v C:\Users\TG\Desktop\updated\final.m 
    Test checkout of feature 'Compiler' failed.

mcc failed.
```

When I type `ver`, I get this:

```
MATLAB Version: 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate  Version 6.1 (Build 7600)
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM mixed mode
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 8.3        (R2014a)
Simulink                                              Version 8.3        (R2014a)
Aerospace Blockset                                    Version 3.13       (R2014a)
Aerospace Toolbox                                     Version 2.13       (R2014a)
Bioinformatics Toolbox                                Version 4.4        (R2014a)
Communications System Toolbox                         Version 5.6        (R2014a)
Computer Vision System Toolbox                        Version 6.0        (R2014a)
Control System Toolbox                                Version 9.7        (R2014a)
Curve Fitting Toolbox                                 Version 3.4.1      (R2014a)
DO Qualification Kit                                  Version 2.3        (R2014a)
DSP System Toolbox                                    Version 8.6        (R2014a)
Data Acquisition Toolbox                              Version 3.5        (R2014a)
Database Toolbox                                      Version 5.1        (R2014a)
Datafeed Toolbox                                      Version 4.7        (R2014a)
Econometrics Toolbox                                  Version 3.0        (R2014a)
Embedded Coder                                        Version 6.6        (R2014a)
Filter Design HDL Coder                               Version 2.9.5      (R2014a)
Financial Instruments Toolbox                         Version 1.3        (R2014a)
Financial Toolbox                                     Version 5.3        (R2014a)
Fixed-Point Designer                                  Version 4.2        (R2014a)
Fuzzy Logic Toolbox                                   Version 2.2.19     (R2014a)
Gauges Blockset                                       Version 2.0.9      (R2014a)
Global Optimization Toolbox                           Version 3.2.5      (R2014a)
HDL Coder                                             Version 3.4        (R2014a)
HDL Verifier                                          Version 4.4        (R2014a)
IEC Certification Kit                                 Version 3.3        (R2014a)
Image Acquisition Toolbox                             Version 4.7        (R2014a)
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 9.0        (R2014a)
Instrument Control Toolbox                            Version 3.5        (R2014a)
LTE System Toolbox                                    Version 1.1        (R2014a)
MATLAB Builder EX                                     Version 2.5        (R2014a)
MATLAB Builder JA                                     Version 2.3.1      (R2014a)
MATLAB Builder NE                                     Version 4.2.1      (R2014a)
MATLAB Coder                                          Version 2.6        (R2014a)
MATLAB Compiler                                       Version 5.1        (R2014a)
MATLAB Report Generator                               Version 3.16       (R2014a)
Mapping Toolbox                                       Version 4.0.1      (R2014a)
Model Predictive Control Toolbox                      Version 4.2        (R2014a)
Model-Based Calibration Toolbox                       Version 4.7        (R2014a)
Neural Network Toolbox                                Version 8.2        (R2014a)
OPC Toolbox                                           Version 3.3.1      (R2014a)
Optimization Toolbox                                  Version 7.0        (R2014a)
Parallel Computing Toolbox                            Version 6.4        (R2014a)
Partial Differential Equation Toolbox                 Version 1.4        (R2014a)
Phased Array System Toolbox                           Version 2.2        (R2014a)
Polyspace Bug Finder                                  Version 1.1        (R2014a)
Polyspace Code Prover                                 Version 9.1        (R2014a)
RF Toolbox                                            Version 2.14       (R2014a)
Real-Time Windows Target                              Version 4.4        (R2014a)
Robust Control Toolbox                                Version 5.1        (R2014a)
Signal Processing Toolbox                             Version 6.21       (R2014a)
SimBiology                                            Version 5.0        (R2014a)
SimDriveline                                          Version 2.6        (R2014a)
SimElectronics                                        Version 2.5        (R2014a)
SimEvents                                             Version 4.3.2      (R2014a)
SimHydraulics                                         Version 1.14       (R2014a)
SimMechanics                                          Version 4.4        (R2014a)
SimPowerSystems                                       Version 6.1        (R2014a)
SimRF                                                 Version 4.2        (R2014a)
Simscape                                              Version 3.11       (R2014a)
Simulink 3D Animation                                 Version 7.1        (R2014a)
Simulink Code Inspector                               Version 2.1        (R2014a)
Simulink Coder                                        Version 8.6        (R2014a)
Simulink Control Design                               Version 4.0        (R2014a)
Simulink Design Optimization                          Version 2.5        (R2014a)
Simulink Design Verifier                              Version 2.6        (R2014a)
Simulink PLC Coder                                    Version 1.7        (R2014a)
Simulink Real-Time                                    Version 6.0        (R2014a)
Simulink Report Generator                             Version 3.16       (R2014a)
Simulink Verification and Validation                  Version 3.7        (R2014a)
Spreadsheet Link EX                                   Version 3.2.1      (R2014a)
Stateflow                                             Version 8.3        (R2014a)
Statistics Toolbox                                    Version 9.0        (R2014a)
Symbolic Math Toolbox                                 Version 6.0        (R2014a)
System Identification Toolbox                         Version 9.0        (R2014a)
SystemTest                                            Version 2.6.7      (R2014a)
Trading Toolbox                                       Version 2.1        (R2014a)
Vehicle Network Toolbox                               Version 2.2        (R2014a)
Wavelet Toolbox            

                       Version 4.13       (R2014a)
```

tried to execute it in the windows cmd

```
C:\Users\TG>mcc
Error: Could not check out a Compiler license:
SIGN= keyword required but missing from the license certificate.
 This is probably because the license is older than the application
 You need to obtain a SIGN= version of this license from your vendor.
Feature:       Compiler
Missing:       SIGN1=
License path:  C:\Users\TG\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2014a_licenses;G:\M
ATLAB\R2014a\licenses\license.dat;G:\MATLAB\R2014a\licenses\license.lic;G:\MATLA
B\R2014a\licenses\license_TG-PC_271282_R2014a.lic;
FlexNet Licensing error:-114,582
For further information, refer to the FlexNet Licensing documentation,
available at "www.flexerasoftware.com"..
```

Comment: You don't need to show us all of the toolboxes you have.  All you have to state is that you have MATLAB Builder, Coder and Compiler installed, which is enough.

Comment: What compiler are you using with which matlab version? Is it possible you are mixing 32bit and 64bit versions here? If you recently reinstalled or updated matlab, run `mex -setup` again.

Comment: Stupid question: You *have* purchased a license for the Matlab compiler, have you?

Comment: @Daniel no i havent updated ,reinstalled matlab i am running 2014a

Comment: R2014a 32bit or 64 bit? What compiler are you using?

Comment: This may help: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103563-why-do-i-receive-a-license-manager-error-114-when-starting-matlab-or-in-the-debug-log-file-on-the-l